# Swift: playAgainstComputer-variable changes from true to false when I navigate between my viewControllers

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

I am working on a swift related iOS-app in Xcode where I have two viewControllers: SecondViewController and GameViewController. I am using a boolean variable, playAgainstComputer, to decide if the game should be against a computer or another player. I have noticed that when I set playAgainstComputer to true in SecondViewController and navigate to GameViewControler, the value of playAgainstComputer automatically changes to false.

Here is my code where I set playAgainstComputer to true after user press on button "Or play against computer" in SecondViewController:

```
@IBAction func btnPlayNPC(_ sender: UIButton) {
       playAgainstComputer = true
        print("playAgainstComputer: \(playAgainstComputer)")
        performSegue(withIdentifier: TO_GAME_SCREEN, sender: self)
    }
```

And here is the code in my GameViewController where I notice that playAgainstComputer changes to false:

```
 @IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
        let index = sender.tag
        if boardArray[index] == "" {
            
            if currentPlayer == 1 {
                boardArray[index] = "X"
                
            } else {
                boardArray[index] = "O"
            }
            
            sender.setTitle(boardArray[index], for: .normal)
            
            switchPlayers()
            
            if currentPlayer == 1 {
                turnSign.text = playerOneName
            } else {
                turnSign.text = playerTwoName
            }
            
            if let winnerMessage = checkForWinner() {
                self.winner = winnerMessage
                myAlertMessage(winnerMessage: winnerMessage)
            } else if !boardArray.contains("") {
                myAlertMessage(winnerMessage: "It's a tie!")
            }
            print("playAgainstComputer: \(playAgainstComputer), currentPlayer: \(currentPlayer)")
            if playAgainstComputer && currentPlayer == 2 {
                print("HERE")
                playAgainstNPC()
                makeComputerMove()
            }
        }
    }
```

I don't know if this part is relevant but if it is then here is my code where I create my variable in a swift file:

```
import Foundation

class GameSettings {
    static let shared = GameSettings()
    var playAgainstComputer = false
}
```

First of all I have double-checked that I am using the same instance of GameSettings in both SecondViewController and GameViewController to ensure that the playAgainstComputer variable is set the same way in both view controllers.
Then I have used print statements to track the value of the playAgainstComputer variable when pressing the "Or play against computer" button in SecondViewController. I have confirmed that playAgainstComputer is set to true when the button is pressed, which is the desired behavior.
I have looked for any code sections in GameViewController that could potentially change the value of playAgainstComputer from true to false, but I am not certain that I have found any such sections.
I also have attempted to use the playAgainstComputer variable in GameViewController, but I notice that the value changes from true to false when navigating from SecondViewController to GameViewController. This results in my computer player not functioning as expected.

Comment: Your line `playAgainstComputer = true` does not have any effect on the `GameSettings.shared` instance. I assume you're setting a local variable named playAgainstComputer in each VC to the value of `GameSettings.shared.playAgainstComputer`? You need to modify the variable directly on the shared instance instead.

Comment: I have implemented that now so that I modify the variable directly on the shared instance instead. But now I notice that my variable is false even from the beginning when I press my button. Here is my code: ```@IBAction func btnPlayNPC(_ sender: UIButton) {
        GameSettings.shared.playAgainstComputer = true
        print("playAgainstComputer: \(playAgainstComputer)")
        performSegue(withIdentifier: TO_GAME_SCREEN, sender: self)
    }
    ```  @TrentMeyer

Comment: Again in the comment, you're printing out the local copy of `playAgainstComputer`. Take @Mykyta iOS's recommendation and always access the variable as `GameSettings.shared.playAgainstComputer`. Read up on [value and reference types](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=10) to get a better understanding of why we are recommending you do this.

Comment: Thank you so much you helped me solve this problem @TrentMeyer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to have a single source of trust, you can access the variable as `GameSettings.shared.playAgainstComputer` every time you're referring it.

The button action will look like:

```
@IBAction func btnPlayNPC(_ sender: UIButton) {
    GameSettings.shared.playAgainstComputer = true
    print("playAgainstComputer: \(GameSettings.shared.playAgainstComputer)")
    performSegue(withIdentifier: TO_GAME_SCREEN, sender: self)
}
```

Your check after player's move will look like:

```
print("playAgainstComputer: \(GameSettings.shared.playAgainstComputer), currentPlayer: \(currentPlayer)")
if GameSettings.shared.playAgainstComputer && currentPlayer == 2 {
    print("HERE")
    playAgainstNPC()
    makeComputerMove()
}
```